# Escaping of this reference in java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading java concurrency in practice. I read one segment which is as follows :

```
public class ThisEscape {
  public ThisEscape (EventSource source) {
     source.registerListener(
        new EventListener () {
           public void onEvent (Event e){
              doSomething(e);
           }
        }); 
  }
}
```

```
When the inner event listener instance is published, so is the enclosing ThisEscape instance
```

Can anyone please help me understand what this exactly means? I am unable to understand this concept.

```
Page 28
listing 3.7 diagram
section 3.2.1
```

Comment: @BasilBourque just fixed the minor typo and added the book reference

Comment: While this is true for now, it may change if you [compile it with Java 18](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8277604) - if `doSomething` is static and `EventListener` is not serializable.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn but could you please explain me what is the problem with above snippet. How is the reference escaping in above code ?

Comment: FYI, in MarkDown, use a greater-than (“>”) for quotations. The triple-backtick is for code, not quotes.